# UIActivityViewControlloer don't show thumbnail for links

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, ipad, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am developing an iOS app that uses the UIActivityViewController to share some text and a Url. In the Facebook and Twitter services it shows a thumbnail of the site located at the URL.

Unfortunately, the site in question does not look very good at all in the thumbnail. So currently the thumbnail has a negative value in the share dialog. I would either like to prevent the thumbnail from displaying, or supply my own image for the thumbnail. What is the best method to do this?

I would like to avoid having to create my own service and/or dialog.

I have tried adding an image to the item list, however that adds a bunch of services I don't want and adds the Image to the email action and adds the image to a photo album on facebook. The first problem I can get around by blacklisting actions I don't want. And I can make my own UIActivityItemProvider to stop the email problem. However, I have no idea how to prevent the facebook problem. (See [How do I customize a UIActivityViewController to show a URL link when posting to facebook and twitter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657817/how-do-i-customize-a-uiactivityviewcontroller-to-show-a-url-link-when-posting-to)).

Here is a screenshot of the facebook sharing dialog:
[image]

Comment: can you post your UIActivityViewController current image?

Comment: I posted a screenshot

Comment: I have also tried setting <meta name="og:image" ... > and <link rel="image_src" ...> which causes the correct image to appear in the Facebook timeline, but still has no affect in the iPad app