# Displaying posted via 'appname'

Tags: ios, facebook, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am using `UIActivityViewController` to share content on Facebook. It displays `'Posted via iOS'` in Facebook.

But I want it to display the `app_name` instead of `iOS`. Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: Can you try to read Facebook SDK documentation? Since you didn't use Facebook SDK, it will be posted "via iOS".

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I customize a UIActivityViewController to show a URL link when posting to facebook and twitter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657817/how-do-i-customize-a-uiactivityviewcontroller-to-show-a-url-link-when-posting-to)

Answer (score 1):

1. create FB app id from here developers.facebook.com for your app.
2. In your info.plist add a key:-FacebookAppID value:- your fb app id.
3. In URl scheme write fbYourFBAppID
4. get your Facebook app reviewd and published by Facebook

Answer (score -1):

There is **NO** way to include your Facebook App name via `UIActivityViewController`.

To use your Facebook App name, you should use Facebook SDK to share content instead.

Comment: not true, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547616/sharing-with-ios-6-0-native-facebook-integration-posted-via-my-app-name/12605241#12605241

Comment: @PeterLapisu If you read carefully your quoted answer, it involves manual process by Facebook. My answer remains correct, as I said, there is no way to include Facebook App name via `UIActivityViewController`, which is OP's asking.

Comment: Also, it is much easier to create a new Facebook App than to seek for Facebook's approval on special case. Agree?

Comment: there is no manual process anymore, it should be done automatically, as soon as you setup and verify your facebook app

Comment: Good to hear that, but please provide reference for OP.